# Modify display of tag-filtered posts when reviewing

Tags: feature-request, review, design

When filtering [normal posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) by a favourite tag, only posts that have a second matching favourite tag are rendered orange.

When filtering any of the four [review lists](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers?pagesize=15&filter=day) on SO by tags, and the tag I filter by happens to be a favourite tag of mine, *ALL* posts are rendered with that orange-like colour background (unless they have a second tag I chose to ignore -  the 'faded out' display works as usual).

I'd like this to be changed to the default behavior that the "normal" posts are showing, ie. don't list all posts orange.

(I didn't give any concrete links showing this, since obviously not everyone has the same favourite tags.)